# Postgresql select related tags (many to many)

Tags: sql, postgresql, relationship

I have a VIEW named review, which is related to a cars table, and the cars table have a many to many relationship with table tags (through join table named cars_tags), but what I need is retrieve the reviews from the cars which are related with some tags, AND at same time related to another tags. What I have today is the following SQL code:

```sql
SELECT  "cars"."review".* 
FROM "cars"."review" 
    LEFT JOIN cars.cars ON (cars.review.car_id = cars.cars.id) 
    LEFT JOIN cars.makes ON (cars.cars.make_id = cars.makes.id) 
    LEFT JOIN cars.cars_tags ON (cars.cars.id = cars.cars_tags.car_id) 
    LEFT JOIN cars.tags ON (cars.cars_tags.tag_id = cars.tags.id) 
WHERE (cars.tags.id IN ('91782e95-8c5d-4254-82ab-b11a21306c18')) 
    AND (cars.tags.id IN ('031cec30-df27-471e-858d-53c3d9657c8a')) 
ORDER BY "cars"."review"."score" DESC LIMIT 100
```

This SQL brings me NO results, but I am sure that there are cars which are related to first id:'91782e95-8c5d-4254-82ab-b11a21306c18'AND '031cec30-df27-471e-858d-53c3d9657c8a' at same time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your query is saying - "only bring back results where `cars.tags.id` is in '917...' AND `cars.tags.id` is in '031...' at the same time".  Surely no single tag can be two different things at once!  Try `cars.tags.id in ('917...', '031...')`, which effectively says "bring back tags that match *either* of these conditions"

Comment: But exactly what I need is the results wich are related to ONE ID, and OTHER ID at same time

Comment: I'm misunderstanding you - nothing can ever satisfy X = 'A' AND X = 'B'.  What do you mean by 'related'?  EDIT:  Wait, I think I get it, give me a minute

Answer (score 0):

[`bool_or`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

```
select r.col1, r.col2 
from
    cars.review r
    left join
    cars.cars on r.car_id = cars.id
    inner join
    cars.cars_tags on cars.id = cars_tags.car_id
    inner join
    cars.tags on cars_tags.tag_id = tags.id 
group by r.col1, r.col2 
having
    bool_or (tags.id = '91782e95-8c5d-4254-82ab-b11a21306c18')
    and
    bool_or (tags.id = '031cec30-df27-471e-858d-53c3d9657c8a')
order by r.score desc
limit 100
```

`exists` version:

```
select col1, col2 
from cars.review
where exists (
    select 1
    from 
        cars.cars
        inner join
        cars.cars_tags on cars.id = cars_tags.car_id
        inner join
        cars.tags on cars_tags.tag_id = tags.id
    where review.car_id = cars.id
    group by 1
    having
        bool_or (tags.id = '91782e95-8c5d-4254-82ab-b11a21306c18')
        and
        bool_or (tags.id = '031cec30-df27-471e-858d-53c3d9657c8a')
)
order by score desc
limit 100
```

Comment: This works fine, but I have too many fields on tables to use group by for every table. But thanks, I thing I will use that

Comment: @AndréCavallari Check the `exists` version

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you're interested in reviews for a car that has 2 specific tags.

This can be done with the query below. I've removed the reference to cars.make as you weren't retrieving any data from it.  Also I've removed the reference to cars.tags as the only information you were using was the tag id which is in the cars_tags table.

```
SELECT  "cars"."review".* 
FROM "cars"."review"
WHERE 
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cars.cars_tags 
        WHERE cars.cars_tags.car_id = cars.review.cars_id 
        AND cars.cars_tags.tag_id = '91782e95-8c5d-4254-82ab-b11a21306c18')
AND
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cars.cars_tags 
        WHERE cars.cars_tags.car_id = cars.review.cars_id 
        AND cars.cars_tags.tag_id = '9031cec30-df27-471e-858d-53c3d9657c8a')
ORDER BY "cars"."review"."score" DESC LIMIT 100
```

The query simply finds all reviews where there exists a cars_tags entry for the two tag_id's you're after.